# Bug using Japanese IME in react-input-mask

Tags: javascript, reactjs, credit-card, input-mask

When I input full-width characters, the existing input are pushing to the right hand side.

See the bug here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEkms.jpg

How can I prevent this to happen since it's working when using normal numeric characters.

```
    <InputMask
      mask={mask}
      value={stateValue}
      onClick={() => setShowMask(true)}
      onChange={(e: any) => handleChange(e)}
      onBlur={() => handleBlur(stateValue)}
      placeholder={
        texts?.placeholder ||
        i18n.t('placeholder_countryCode', {
          field: texts?.field || i18n.t('default_fieldName')
        })
      }
      alwaysShowMask={showMask}
      formatChars={{
        x: '[0-9０-９]'
      }}
      ref={innerRef}
    >
      {(inputProps: any) => (
        <Input
          {...inputProps}
          {...innerProps}
          type='text'
          required={isRequired}
          invalid={invalid || error.status !== true}
          className={textFieldClassName}
          style={inputInlineStyle}
        />
      )}
    </InputMask>
```

Comment: So what do you expect us to do about it?

Comment: How could I prevent the bug since it's pushing the input in right side when using Japanese Keyboard.

Comment: We aren't here to help with using hardware. This looks like a case of general hardware/software which should be asked on [su]. If you can provide an error or are asking for help with a script  you created for it that doesn't work as intended then we can help. But currently I don't think this is an SO question. (But I could be wrong)

Comment: Hardware isn't problem here. Did you open this? https://imgur.com/0os1ZqS ? This is the bug I'm asking. Lol

Comment: Yes but general software is also SU. And a keyboard seems very general to me. I just don't see a way this matches all the SO boxes. It's not a bad question. But I just think it's on the wrong site. But we'll see what the others think.